# Magento2 custom page templates

Tags: magento2

I have developed a custom Magento2 theme and created a Generic Page layout at Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml. In that layout i have configured my custom generic layout to use Header - Content - Footer. I have set the menu positions and the appropriate blocks.

I am now looking for some static pages to use a template and within Content Area (of the Generic page layout). For example Home page must have a banner slider and Contact page must have a Google map. Is there any way to configure it to my theme?? Is that the page_layout section of my theme??? I cannot find any customization there.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at default Core file? For example

vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml ?
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml

```
<div class="footer-container">
<div class="footer">
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml() ?>
    <p class="bugs"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Help Us Keep Magento Healthy') ?> - <a
        href="http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking"
        target="_blank"><strong><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Report All Bugs') ?></strong></a>
    </p>
    <address><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getCopyright() ?></address>
</div>
```